# Retrieving data from excel and storing it in Access

Tags: excel-2007, ms-access-2007

I have several excel workbooks that each have a desire spreadsheet that will continually be updated with data by non-tech users and the process now is that the data is being manually entered into an Access DB through an Access GUI that is linked to the DB tables. To eliminate the manual input I was thinking I can import the data into access then run queries to update the DB tables with the temp table that is made by the imported data. The problem is that since its several workbooks, my mindset is that I would have to create a table for each workbook( aiming for desired spreadsheet) and it can be up to 50. Is their a easier way to do this because to me doing that everytime would be just about the same amount of work to manually enter the info in my opinion. Keep in mind that I can't do macros in excel due to computer restrictions. Any help on understanding how this could work, maybe the easy approach is going over my head because I am not thinking straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link Excel spreadsheets as tables in Access, furthermore, you can name the linked tables whatever you want (see Transferspreadsheet method of DoCmd). You can iterate through the fifty spreadsheets linking, updating and then deleting the link, or simply have 50 linked tables. Furthermore, using the IN keyword, you can create queries without linking the Excel sheets at all.

Comment: You're assuming, of course, that the structure of all the spreadsheets is identical. This would be a rational assumption, but not necessarily correct!

Comment: @David-W-Fenton I am not necessarily assuming anything. I offer a number of possibilities, including 50 linked tables and a set of queries using IN.

Comment: what do you mean by using the IN keyword, Are you saying in Access using VBA I could call those individual spreadsheets and store that information in Access?

Comment: Some notes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689087/where-in-query-with-two-recordsets-in-access-vba/2689151#2689151  OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762641/ms-access-auto-link-excel-spreadsheets/3762758#3762758